# Disable two column mode for separate part

Tags: document-classes, multicol

I am writing a document using the `report` class in two column mode, but I need a `\section` to spread across both columns, but how can I set that?

Something like

```
\documentclass[10pt,danish,a4paper,twoside,twocolumn]{report}
\input{preamble.tex}
\begin{document}

% This section should spread over both columns
\section{Name}

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If this is for a figure only, use `\begin{figure*}` instead of `\begin{figure}`. cf https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30988/105230

Answer (score 87, accepted):

There is a switch: `\onecolumn`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,twocolumn, english]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum, babel}
%\input{preamble.tex}
\begin{document}
\lipsum

% This section should spread over both columns
\onecolumn
\section{Name}

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

But the section has to start on a new page. Go back to twocolumn with? Yes, `\twocolumn`.

Comment: Can I do it without starting a new page?

Comment: Only if you use the multicol package. You know how to get the manual? Type `texdoc multicol` on the commandline. Beware: the name of the environment is »multicols«.

Comment: So if I write the Whole page in multicol, I can change it on one section of a page? Or it is also going to display 2 pages?

Comment: Just used this solution for a paper I'm writing.  Very helpful for putting full-page tables in the middle of documents.  Thanks!

Comment: @AriB.Friedman Just to let you know (maybe you already do), the correct way to have a table spreading accross two columns is using `\begin{table*}` and figures with `\begin{figure*}`, with their corresponding ends.

Comment: @Hans, that feels like an answer rather than a comment? Can you elaborate on why it's better? Thanks, Ari

Comment: Can I apply this for all document?

Comment: @alper Ask a new question, please: apply what where? Include MWE.

Comment: @KeksDose the solution was pretty simple adding `\onecolumn` on top of `\begin{document}` solved it

Comment: For listings, use float=*t if you want the code snippet to span across two columns (in a two column document).
[Ref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204871/listing-spanning-two-columns-with-ieee-template)
e.g.: \lstinputlisting[caption = test,label = test, float=*t]{test_code.py}

Comment: this helped me today. Thanks. I used `\towcolumn` as well.