# how to remove half line in twocolumn in first page?

Tags: fancyhdr, two-column, landscape, article

I want half line in twocolumn article but in first page like this 
**first page**
[image]

**second page**
[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[margin=1cm,top=1.3cm,bottom=1.3cm,headsep=5mm]
{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,fancybox}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}  
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.7pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.7pt}   
    \begin{document}
hellow hellow hellow    hellow hellow hellow    hellow hellow hellow    
hellow hellow hellow    hellow hellow hellow    
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Have you looked into using the [multicol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package?

Comment: \twocolumn[text] will start a new page and place the text across the whole page.

Comment: I found the solution using http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88387/disable-two-column-mode-for-separate-part