# How do you a make onecolumn page and then the next page a twocolumn?

Tags: two-column, multicol

I have a problem making my ACM latex format, I am using the SIG proceedings. When I insert a `\onecolumn` it creates a page on top.
What I want to do is like this.[image]

and then the next page is like this.
[image]

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, [you need `multicols` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88387/disable-two-column-mode-for-separate-part#comment191551_88415).

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to use the multicol package. You get the manual with `texdoc multicol`and beware, the environment is called `multicols` - mind the s.

That said, just put `\twocolumn`at the end of p. 1 and the rest of the document starting from the next page will have two columns.