# I want to set full page instead of using two columns?

Tags: two-column, geometry

I am writing a solution manual which I have already completed. I want the normal page to write the preface, acknowledgement and dedication just as the page on which contents are written without splitting into columns. I do not know how to set the page normally to write the preface. I am providing full files with all codes.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=7in, top=1in, bottom=0.8in, twocolumn, twoside]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{{Graphics/}}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand\aug{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\begin{document}
%\include{Frontmatter/colophon}
\tableofcontents
%\Mainmatter
\include{Mainmatter/Chapter-1}
\end{document}
```

I need the preface page like the contents page without splitting into two columns. I need two columns geometry just after the contents table. How can I set this.

Comment: The `split` environment from the `cuted` package might help.

Comment: Does this question help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88387/disable-two-column-mode-for-separate-part/88415

Answer (score 2):

Put `\onecolumn` when you want one column and `\twocolumn` when you want two columns

```
% onetwocolprob2.tex  SE 555696
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}   %%% added

\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=7in, top=1in, bottom=0.8in, twocolumn, twoside]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{{Graphics/}}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand\aug{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\begin{document}

\onecolumn                   %%% added

%\include{Frontmatter/colophon}
\frontmatter                 %%% added
Some front matter. \lipsum   %%% added
\tableofcontents
%\Mainmatter
\mainmatter                 %%% added
\twocolumn                  %%% added
%\include{Mainmatter/Chapter-1}
\chapter{One}               %%% added
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I have added text to be printed to your MWE so that you can see the result. BTW your MWE is not exactly minimal as your preamble includes many irrelevant packages wrt to your actual problem; I didn't waste my removing them. --- GOM

Comment: I know how make it one column. But need pull page sir like the contents page. If I will add the command of one column I just can use the half side of page as one column.