# Subfigures side by side with captions

Tags: captions, subfloats

I am using the following code to put my two figures side by side with different captions,

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.2in]{a}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.2in]{b}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption place holder}
\end{figure*}
```

I get the following output: [image: output]

However, I want to position both my images vertically same line, like the following:

Desired output: [image: desired]

Comment: IJust curious: Why are you using the "starred" version of the `figure` environment? Is your document maybe being typeset in `twocolumn` mode? If so, the only place where LaTeX will place a double-wide float is at the top of the page, which would make the `[t!]` location specifier unnecessary.

Comment: @Mico, yes. I was using a document in `twocolumn` mode. In MWE, I should have deleted that part, sorry.

Comment: Can @Sait show the usepackages please?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Use the `t` option for the alignment of the subfigures:

```latex
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.2in]{a}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1.2in]{b}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum,Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption place holder}
\end{figure*}
```

Using this, both images will be aligned on top:

[image]

Comment: ...or as an alternative use the `\captionbox` command instead of the `subfigure` environment. `\captionbox`es will be aligned by the first line of the caption automatically.

Comment: Which pkg is required to use subfigure?

Comment: The `subcaption` package is the one for that :)

Comment: What's the meaning of "~"?

Comment: @skan It's a non-breaking space. The subfigures don't stay next to each other when there is an empty line between them, so the space was added. Alternatively you could omit that line – it would just give you different horizontal spacing between the subfigures.

Comment: what is figure*?

Comment: Can I know what is there options of the alignment of subfigure? beside `b`, `t`? Is there a list to check all the options?

Comment: @Hao S (3 years later) the starred version `*` of the `figure` environment (i.e. `figure*`) is for displaying a figure across the total width of the page when using a two-column document (see this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30988/262081)).

Comment: @aan You can find a list in the `subcaption` [manual on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf), for e.g. section 3 (p. 6 of manual version 1.5 2022-02-20) with subcation v1.2: "Beside the outer-pos values of ‘c’, ‘t’, and ‘b’, the subcaption package also offers the values ‘T’ and ‘B’ additionally which align the subfigure at the very top resp. bottom. (In contrast ‘t’ and ‘b’ align the subfigure at the top resp. bottom baseline.)"

Comment: Note also the percent symbol `%` on the line just before the non-breaking space `~`. This is critical - without it, you'll get a line break between the subfigures and they'll appear top and bottom.

Comment: If I copy and paste this code into Overleaf and just change the filenames for the figures, then it gives me the images stacked atop each other. It also gives the subfigure captions as normal captions. I have downloaded the subcaption.sty file and added it to my Overleaf document. Can anyone explain this issue?