# how to draw multiple graphs next to each other with labels

Tags: pstricks, labels, graphs

How to draw multiple graphs next to each other in a document? Also, how to name each graph with a label? One more thing is I need to show an dashed edge to intersect the graph edge, in that case how the edge or dashed line should be represented?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
$
\psmatrix[colsep=2.5cm,rowsep=1.5cm,mnode=circle]
&v_0&v_0\\
0&&&0\\
&v_1&v_1
\ncline{->}{2,1}{1,2}^{0}
\ncline{->}{1,2}{1,3}^{0}
\ncline{->}{1,3}{2,4}_{0}
\ncarc[arcangle=-10]{->}{1,2}{3,3}_{1}
\ncarc[arcangle=10]{->}{3,2}{1,3}_{1}
\ncarc[arcangle=-30]{->}{2,1}{3,2}_{1}
\ncarc[arcangle=30]{->}{2,1}{3,2}_{2}
\ncarc[arcangle=-30]{->}{1,3}{2,4}_{2}
\ncarc[arcangle=30]{->}{1,3}{2,4}^{3}
\ncline{->}{3,3}{2,4}_{1}
\ncline{->}{3,2}{3,3}_{0}
\endpsmatrix
$ 
\vspace{1in}
\end{document}
```

Also, can I name these individual graphs with labels?

Since these graphs have to be included in an IEEE template I am planning to generate graphs in pstricks and then include the pdf with `\includegraphics` in LaTeX.

Comment: For figures side-by-side and labelled subfigures, have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119984/subfigures-side-by-side-with-captions)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the "dashed edge" - which of the graph edges should it intersect?

Comment: @HarishKumar its ok sir. I used pstricks so asked in it. if any other way possible please let me know.

Comment: @Thruston dashed edge in the sense \linestyle=dashed which produces a dashed edge. My question is can we intersect an edge with a dashed or dotted edge?

Comment: I think you can use automata from tikz. Please check the pgfmanual (`texdoc pgfmanual` from command prompt.)