# table to the left of an image

Tags: tables, tabularx, circuitikz

I need to put a table next to this circuit (1), as in the following image (2). Tranks in advance!

[image]
[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\begin{circuitikz} 
    \draw
    (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
    (opamp.-) to[R,l_=$R_s$] (-3, 0.5) 
    (opamp.-) |-  (-1, 1.5) to[R,l^=$R_f$] (1, 1.5) -| (opamp.out);
    \draw (-3,0.5) node[ground,below]{};
 \draw  (opamp.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,0);    
\draw  (opamp.out) to[short,*-] ++(0,0)to[short](2,0)node[right]{$V_o$};
\draw (opamp.+)node[left]{$V_i$}
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please add some clarifications: What exactly is the problematic part? Is it the placement of circuit and table side by side? Is it the vertical alignment? Is it the colored background? What did you try so far?

Comment: This has really nothing to do with `circuitikz`... ;-) it is the same as aligning a `tikzpicture` and whatever else... for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424121/placing-a-tikz-picture-and-table-side-by-side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Align at center:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{circuitikz}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)] 
    \draw
      (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
      (opamp.-) to[R,l_=$R_s$] (-3, 0.5) 
      (opamp.-) |-  (-1, 1.5) to[R,l^=$R_f$] (1, 1.5) -| (opamp.out);
    \draw (-3,0.5) node[ground,below]{};
    \draw (opamp.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,0);    
    \draw (opamp.out) to[short,*-] ++(0,0) to[short] (2,0) node[right] {$V_o$};
    \draw (opamp.+)node[left]{$V_i$};
  \end{circuitikz}
  \qquad
  \begin{tabular}[c]{lr}
    a & b \\
    aa & bb
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Align at top:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{circuitikz}[baseline={(0, 1.5)}] 
    \draw
      (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
      (opamp.-) to[R,l_=$R_s$] (-3, 0.5) 
      (opamp.-) |-  (-1, 1.5) to[R,l^=$R_f$] (1, 1.5) -| (opamp.out);
    \draw (-3,0.5) node[ground,below]{};
    \draw (opamp.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,0);    
    \draw (opamp.out) to[short,*-] ++(0,0) to[short] (2,0) node[right] {$V_o$};
    \draw (opamp.+)node[left]{$V_i$};
  \end{circuitikz}
  \qquad
  \begin{tabular}[t]{lr}
    a & b \\
    aa & bb
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. It could be interesting to use, for example, `baseline=(A.out)` and then centering the table. That way you can align the `tabular` to any component of the circuit.