# How to add a description after each column at the bottom?

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I want to add a description "column a" for the first column, "column b" for the second column, "column c" for the third column. How to do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-b}
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-c}

      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-b}
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-c}

      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-b}
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-c}
      \caption{Column A $\rightarrow$ Column B $\rightarrow$ Column C. }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: table_grid**strong text**]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with tabular for more control:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{1.5mm}}c@{\hspace{1.5mm}}c}
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}&
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-b}&
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-c}\\[0.1mm]
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}&
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-b}&
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-c}\\[0.1mm]
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}&
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-b}&
      \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-c}\\[0.1mm]
      (a) &
      (b) &
      (c)
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Column A $\rightarrow$ Column B $\rightarrow$ Column C. }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use Subfigures, see [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119984/subfigures-side-by-side-with-captions).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}



\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
      \includegraphics{a}
      \includegraphics{a}
      \includegraphics{a}
      \subcaption{caption of Column A}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
      \includegraphics{b}
      \includegraphics{b}
      \includegraphics{b}
      \subcaption{caption of Column B}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
      \includegraphics{c}
      \includegraphics{c}
      \includegraphics{c}
      \subcaption{caption of Column C}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption of all the figures }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You are able to nest subfigures within the figure-environment.

[image]

Comment: aww :( I was too slow.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `subfigure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.32\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
      \caption{Column A $\rightarrow$}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.32\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
      \caption{Column B $\rightarrow$}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.32\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
      \caption{Column C. }
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption for all the three subfigures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]