# Change numbering of subfigure

Tags: subfloats

I have two figures with multiple subfigures in each. The subfigures in my first figure are named a), b), c), d). In my second figure, I want my subfigures to start numbering where my first figure ends, e), f), g)). Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance

\usepackage{subcaption}

code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim={2cm 7cm 2cm 6cm},clip]{figures/Ellipse10.pdf}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim={2cm 7cm 2cm 6cm},clip]{figures/Ellipse25.pdf}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim={2cm 7cm 2cm 6cm},clip]{figures/Ellipse15.pdf}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}
%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim={2cm 7cm 2cm 6cm},clip]{figures/Ellipse30.pdf}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim={2cm 7cm 2cm 6cm},clip]{figures/Ellipse50.pdf}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}
%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim={2cm 7cm 2cm 6cm},clip]{figures/Ellipse70.pdf}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}
%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim={2cm 7cm 2cm 6cm},clip]{figures/Ellipse90.pdf}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I know of at least four ways to get “subfigures”, you should tell us which one you're using.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. 
i'm using the same aproach as in this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119984/subfigures-side-by-side-with-captions

Comment: instead of link please provide in question a complete small document beginning with `\documentclass ...` and ending `\end{document}`. help us to help you!

Comment: Put `\setcounter{subfigure}{4}` inside the 1st `subfigure` within the 2nd `figure`. `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}\setcounter{subfigure}{3}`

Comment: Thank you all. Sigur, setconter worked perfecty, Much apreciated

Comment: No, don't use the dirty `\setcounter` hack. This would not suppress the increasing of the main figure counter, and it would make trouble when using `hyperref`. Use `\ContinuedFloat` instead.

Answer (score 4):

With the `\ContinuedFloat` macro from the `caption` package, the previous figure will be continued and the numbering will be correct:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```