# How to fix overflow text in \hbox to new line

Tags: box

I have to display 4 images in two columns and two rows. The text in \hbox is so long that's why it is overriding the second image text in the next column. How to make the first image text break after a certain width so it will come into the new line. I have used \linebreak, \ but none of them is working.

```
\hbox to\linewidth{%
    \hfil%
    \vbox{%
        \hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{sampleimage1.png}}%
        \hbox to 5cm {Sample text 1}
    }%
    \hfil%
    \vbox{%
        \hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{sampleimage2.png}}%
        \hbox{Sample text 2}
    }%
    \hfil%
}
\hbox to\linewidth{%
    \hfil%
    \vbox{%
        \hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{sampleimage3.png}}%
        \hbox{Sample text 3}
    }%
    \hfil%
    \vbox{%
        \hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{sampleimage4.png}}%
        \hbox{Sample text 4}
    }%
    \hfil%
}
\caption{caption text}
```

[image: Here is the output]

Comment: First of all always give full examples others can copy and test as is, not sniplets like this. Secondly are you writing in plain tex? If not why thise nested constructions? And why aren't you then using parbox instead it even supports line breaks.

Comment: Lastly it us probably easier to control the size of an image using width not scale

Comment: I have problem with the text not image

Comment: It is all related, just look at the last one

Comment: How about using [subcaptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119985/113035)?

Comment: neither `\hbox` nor `\vbox`  should appear in a latex document and if you use them in this way they will not react normally to any latex constructs, no latex box commands use boxes unguarded by `\leavevmode` in this way.

Comment: `\hbox` naturally forces the text to be on one line so `\\ `, `\newline` etc do not produce line breaks. You could put a `\parbox` inside the `\hbox` but as noted above the real issue is that the `\hbox` should not be there.

Comment: Why not use minipages?

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use low level commands if you don't know what they do.

Isn't the following simpler?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  p{0.48\textwidth}
  p{0.48\textwidth}
  @{}
}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 &
Sample Text 2 Sample Text 2 Sample Text 2 Sample Text 3 \\[2ex]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
Sample Text 3 Sample Text 3 Sample Text 3 Sample Text 3 &
Sample Text 4 Sample Text 4 Sample Text 4 Sample Text 4
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Caption text Caption text Caption text Caption text Caption text}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But can you please change the caption text of images because it is considered as plagiarised for my report.

Comment: @RohitSuthar Plagiarism? It should be a joke, but unfortunately it might be (very sadly) true. Next time a thesis with the words “I love you” not properly equipped with a citation will be considered plagiarism.

Comment: I'm also shocked!! Anyway Thanks!!