# How to make subfigures next to each other

Tags: graphics

If I use the code from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119984/subfigures-side-by-side-with-captions) thread It will look like in the image. The user packages I have are
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}

But for some reason, it does not work, at all? Where in the code do I enter the image name?[image]

Comment: You can't use all three packages `subfigure`, `subfig` and `subcaption` inside of a single document. Since the first one is considered deprecated, decide which of the latter two you want to use and stick to a single package.

Comment: Does it matter which one I use of the two last ones?

Comment: @JohnGreger: Each package has its own implementation (macros and the like). However, in some cases, since they deal with the same subject matter, there may be some macros that overlap between packages and therefore could be overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example uses the package `subcaption` for two upper figures side by side.

To test it with your images, put them in the same directory as the `.tex` document. Later you can move them to another directory by adding the path.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption} %  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{figure}[ht!]  % with two subfigures included
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.40\textwidth}
            \centering
            % first image
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}  %  <<< image name 1
            \caption{Lorem ipsum}
            \label{fig:Lorem}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.40\textwidth}
            \centering
            % second image
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-b} %  <<< image name 2
            \caption{Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum}
            \label{fig:ipsum}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption place holder}
    \end{figure}  

    \begin{figure}[ht!] % a single figure
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-grid-100x100pt} % 
            \caption{Single figure named example-grid-100x100pt}
        \label{fig:gris}
    \end{figure}    
    
\end{document}
```