# Putting two-column wide figure in Revtex4-1

Tags: floats, two-column, revtex

I have a problem with APS's revtex4-1.
I want to place an twocolumn-wide figure at the bottom of the page.
I know

```
\begin{figure*}[position]
picture
\end{figure*}
```

in {article} document class 
[position] can be htb! , and I have no problem in {article} in placing pictures on here, top, and bottom.

But!!

in {revtex4-1} document class
[position] is not working! only for t. If I use b, the picture appears on the next page, and  it takes up all paper. I want it to be bottom.

I tried  \usepackage{dblfloatfix}  but it does not work in revtex4-1 and makes error with equation, and so on..(I see revtex4-1 is incompatible with dblfloatfix.)

The following URL is for article class, I have no problem to follow its instruction.

[Displaying a wide figure in a two-column document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/displaying-a-wide-figure-in-a-two-column-document)

Please, Help!

This is my sample code, I manage to put long table at the position where I wanted, but long figure is not!

Thanks,

```
\documentclass[
showkeys,reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose,
%preprint,
%showpacs,preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
floatfix,
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math


%]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}      
\fancyhead{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[C]{}





\begin{document}

\preprint{APS/123-QED}

\title{
%\begin{minipage}{14cm}
Microscopic Images and Micro Vickers Hardness Test of
Fullly Pearlitic High-Carbon Steel Specimens
%\end{minipage}
}
\author{ABCD}
\email{ABCD}
\collaboration{ABCD}
\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
\begin{center}
{\bfseries Abstract}
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\keywords{\lipsum[1]}

\maketitle
%\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
long&long&long&long&long&long&long&long&long&long&long
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\begin{figure*}[b]
                \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{tiger}
                %\linewidth or \textwidth
                \caption{A gull}
                \label{fig:gull}
\end{figure*}

\section{Experiment}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
%
% ****** End of file apssamp.tex ******
```

Comment: Is this for a manuscript you plan to submit to APS? If so, I would recommend against forcing RevTeX4-1 to do something it doesn't want (or isn't designed) to do.

Comment: Never!. I wrote this to do my simple project paper in school. I found that the revtex's configuration and appearance were good but hard to use it. I already know that I don't need to do anything to submit it to APS, they will do for me! :D

Comment: This questioin may be helpful (this works for figures as well as tables): [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430)

Answer (score 24):

I encountered the same problem editing a document under REVTeX.

Thanks for pointing out that only position `[t]` is recognized under the `{figure*}` environment.

A working solution is offered by using the `\onecolumngrid` and `\twocolumngrid` commands

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,...]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
...
\onecolumngrid

\begin{figure}[h] 
\includegraphics{example.eps}
\end{figure}    
\twocolumngrid
...
```

I observed that the double newline after `\onecolumngrid` is essential to avoid the figure merging with the text. However, in my case this statement doesn't seem to hold for `\twocolumngrid`.

Pieter

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have replaced the link with a summary of the solution.

Comment: Wow. I've never thought I would got a re! Thanks for seeing this in 10 months after. I found out what \onecolumngrid and \twocolumngrid do but it does not help me to properly position the long figure....so sad...

Comment: @ Pieter De Beule The double newline after \onecolumngrid is non-intuitive –  thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

I think one hack that works is putting the figure as float inside a minipage widetext environment. For example,

```
\begin{widetext}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sample.png}
            \label{fig:sample}
        \end{figure}    
    \end{minipage}
\end{widetext}
```

Comment: Given you're using `[H]` is the `minipage` actually necessary/useful?

Answer (score 0):

This was a dirty trick that worked for me. I found it on the LaTeX forum. I only had to cut my text at a suitable spot (between the `[CUT HERE]` to reduce empty lines so that it did not look to obvious that I cut the text in half myself).

```latex
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is [CUT HERE]\
\onecolumngrid\
\begin{center}\
\begin{figure}[h]\
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{myfig.pdf}\
\caption{mycaption}\
\end{figure}\
\end{center}\
\twocolumngrid\
[CUT HERE] a sentence, This is a sentence....\
```

I hope this can be useful for some people.