# How to place a figure at the bottom of a two-column page in REVTex?

Tags: graphics, floats, revtex

I am trying to write an article using a template within the APS files of the REVTex 4.2 distribution. I am trying to put a page-wide figure at the bottom of a two-column page. I tried using `dblfloats` and `stfloats` but without any success. I am using `\documentclass[]{revtex4-2}`.

I tried all the possible ways suggested
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53167913/how-to-place-the-figure-at-the-bottom-of-page-in-latex) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235623/placing-a-figure-in-the-bottom-of-a-page-spanning-the-two-columns-of-an-ieee-doc).

Can someone please suggest how to solve this issue?

Comment: revtex simply doesn't support bottom-of-page two-column figures with `figure*` always going top of page, and it uses its own layout so solutions for other classes often don't translate.  Probably the closest you will be able to do is [force placement with `\onecolumngrid` or the `widetext` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160730/106162) but this requires manual tuning and even then may not manage bottom of page.

Comment: @DaiBowen Thank you for the comment. The forced placement using \onecolumngrid seems to be the best alternative.