# Fix wide-figure positioning in 2 column Latex

Tags: floats, two-column

I have a two column formating of latex. I know that I can use `*` to wide the figure in two column: `\begin{figure*}----\end{figure*}`
For fix positioning I know, I have to use `\usepackage{float}` plus using `[H]` in front of figure: `\begin{figure*} [H]----\end{figure*}`; but when I use `[H]`, my figure is disappeared in my compiled pdf. How to solve problem?

Comment: You also can use the `strip` environment  from the `cuted` package, from the `sttools`  bundle, and the `captionof` command (defined in `capt-of` and also in `caption`).

Comment: please post an MWE, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that reproduces the problem

Comment: What do you mean by MWE?

Comment: the document class is as follow: \documentclass[ reprint,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
]{revtex4-1}

Comment: [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE). What's that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001)

Comment: \documentclass[
 reprint,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
%prb,
]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks   = true,
 citecolor    = red
}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\raggedbottom %in command faselaharo kam mikone baiad akharin bashe hamishe
\begin{document}

Comment: not what you ask for but may be helpfull http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/displaying-a-wide-figure-in-a-two-column-document

Comment: Please add code to the question not as a comment. You can not use `[H]` with a two-column float  just do not use `[H]`