# Figure in two-column article

Tags: floats, two-column, tabularx

I have a two-column article document in which I want to place a figure spanning both columns above two (independent) tables (using `tabularx`), one in each column. I've followed the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/displaying-a-wide-figure-in-a-two-column-document), but it gives me tables and figures on separate pages. What am I doing wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure*}

\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{l|X}
1 & Some text\\
2 & Some more text 
\end{tabularx} 

\newpage

\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{l|X}
3 & Some text\\
4 & Some more text 
\end{tabularx} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost right:-) But `figure*` always comes the page *after* it appears in the source so you can't do this on the first page (if you need that you need to do something a bit trickier) and you need `\noindent` to avoid a paragraph indentation making your full width tables not fit on a line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}



\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure*}

aaa

\pagebreak

aaa

\pagebreak

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{l|X}
1 & Some text\\
2 & Some more text 
\end{tabularx} 

\newpage

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{l|X}
3 & Some text\\
4 & Some more text 
\end{tabularx} 

\end{document}
```