# Full-width figures with Pandoc

Tags: two-column, pandoc, markdown, wide-image

I want to produce a figure which spans both columns in a two column layout document, exactly as discussed here: [Displaying a wide figure in a two-column document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/displaying-a-wide-figure-in-a-two-column-document)

I'm writing in Markdown and using Pandoc to convert to Latex, and then to PDF (I like to have the `.tex` intermediate step so that I can see exactly how my work is typeset). I haven't been able to find a way of telling Pandoc to produce a full width image either by using the starred figure environment (as discussed in the afore-linked thread) or by some other mechanism.

I can achieve my desired result by manually tweaking the Latex output by Pandoc to use `figure*`, but that's a bit of a pain as I have to repeat this (by hand) every time I compile a new version of my document from (the Markdown) source.

I could also achieve this by including the raw Latex code in my Markdown file, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution. However, this is what I will fall back to if nothing better is possible.

For completeness, here is the syntax I'm using to include the figure in my Markdown document.

```
![Figure caption](assets/my-figure.png){width=100%}
```

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned that in my post. Yes, that occurred to me too, and that's what I'll fall back to  But I was hoping for a cleaner solution (even a Pandoc filter to add the syntax would be preferable). EDIT: I've updated my question with this.

Comment: Did you find a solution by now?

Comment: Sadly I have not 

Answer (score 1):

To date there is no pure pandoc solution to what you want. However, that may be easily achieved with custom filter. Chime in to pandoc-discuss and ask for help in building a filter for that.

Comment: Is there now a pure pandoc solution?