# How to put figure in centre of page

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have a question. I'm writing paper in two columns form, but I want to place my figure in centre of page instead of column. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Try `figure*`. If that isn't want you want, post a minimal working example i.e. code for a minimal document demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30988/124842

Answer (score 1):

Here, I add my code to place your figure in centre of page instead of column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\begin{figure*}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth,height=3in]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is a figure caption}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[8-14]
\end{document}
```