# How to add an image in a scientific paper that spans columns and is situated after the text?

Tags: graphics, positioning

I want to add an image in a two-column paper in the following manner.
[image]

I have tried using

```
\begin{figure*}
 \centering
...
\end{figure*}
```

but there's an error: `Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles.` I'm new to Latex so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's better to add a minimal working example in order to help everyone knows where your problem comes from.

Comment: Similar question with solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/displaying-a-wide-figure-in-a-two-column-document

Comment: The output loop will be a different problem, in code you have not shown.  However a `figure*` can  not be placed at the bottom in the default code. Several packages add this feature though see https://texfaq.org/FAQ-2colfloat

Comment: @Diaa My problem is the placement of the image and I don't even know where to begin to place the image in that particular spot. My working code would just be a plain two-column document with a table and some text.

Comment: @andc I tried out that code but it puts borders across the entire text and changes the format of the document.

Comment: @David Carlisle Thanks, I read the document, I'll try it out.