# Onecolumn without page break

Tags: two-column

How can I make a `one column` in a `two column` article, without page breaking???

I am writing an article to submit to `NIM`. The article should be 2 columns.
In one of the pages I need to put a wide figure at the top of the page, and then continue with 2 column text, like in the attached Screenshot_1.png...

But the way I am trying this, latex puts the 2 column continuation to a new page...

Is this possible in Latex without page break?

This is how I try:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}

\journal{Nucl. Instrum. Methods A}

\begin{document}

\begin{twocolumn}

   bla, bla, bla

\end{twocolumn}

\onecolumn

\begin{figure}[t]

\begin{center}

\includegraphics[width=17.4cm]{pic/RESULTS_SUM.pdf}

\label{Si_Results}

\end{center}

\end{figure}

\begin{twocolumn}

   bla, bla, bla,

\end{twocolumn}

\end{document}
```

[image: How I want]

Comment: Try with figure* instead of figure.

Comment: Closely related: [Displaying a wide figure in a two-column document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30985/134144)

Comment: Thank you leandris! It works like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the entire text in `two column`, then give the number of columns in class option, please avoid to keep `\begin{twocolumn}...`, example given below:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,12pt,3p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\journal{Nucl. Instrum. Methods A}

\begin{document}

\title{Article title}

\author{Author Name}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

   bla, bla, bla

\lipsum[1-8]

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=17.4cm]{example-image-a}
\label{Si_Results}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

In general, any floats are not allowed in first page of an article...

Comment: better `\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\label{Si_Results}
\end{figure*}`. And inform OP that image will appear on the top of the next page!

Comment: No, not the entire text should be two columns. Title, Author list and the Abstract are in 1 column...

Comment: @tikorost Please refer the edited answer...

Comment: Thanks, it works with figure*. THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad to hear that, if the suggested answer is helpful to fix your issue, then please accept it by clicking the tick mark...

Comment: @MadyYuvi, you also can up-vote OP question ...

Comment: @Zarko Done, and thanks...