# Text is over image and not wrapped around it

Tags: graphics

My problem is image is displayed correctly, however text is not wrapped over the image, but is on top of it, as the image is not there.

Sample code:

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{architecture.png}
  \caption{Mesos architecture}\label{fig:architecture}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: It seems as if you have a twocolumn document and want your image to be as wide as both columns. You can use `figure*` for this.

Comment: @leandriss  I knew that smth was wrong and related to columns, but couldn't figure out what exactly caused the problem and how to fix it. thanks :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Since your question is quite similar to an already existing, older one ([Displaying a wide figure in a two-column document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/displaying-a-wide-figure-in-a-two-column-document)) I have voted to close yours as a duplicate to the previous one.