# How can I make an image full width in the center of page IEEEtran?

Tags: floats, multicolumn, ieeetran, includegraphics, wide-image

I want to make it like this in LaTeX IEEEtran:

[image]

I got this file at [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/displaying-a-wide-figure-in-a-two-column-document/30988). I also tried to apply it in IEEEtran, but it didn't work.

I've tried using  `\twocolumn` and `\onecolum`, but this command makes the image on a separate page separate from the text. Then the `\multicols` command will make it look like four columns for `\multicols{2}` and no changes to `\multicols{1}`.

The command works for files other than IEEEtran, but I've tried it on IEEEtran and it doesn't work.

Here is my code for the figure code

```
\begin{figure*} [!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imagename.png}
\caption{image caption}
  \label{Fig:image label}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the option `keepaspectratio`?

Comment: Off-topic: Since you're setting the width of the image to `\textwidth`, you don't need the `\centering` instruction.

Comment: @Mico, thanks for reminding about '\textwidth'. But 'keepaspectratio' doesn't seem to solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you intent to publish in some IEEE journal, don't do it. They don't allow to have images over two columns on the first page and allow on other pages as enable `figure*`.

If persisting to insert an image in your own way, then see if the package `cuted` works for you (and for the publisher too):

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}  % <---
\usepackage{cuted}    % <===

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{strip} % <--- defined in "cuted"
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\captionof{figure}{image caption}
\label{Fig:image label}
\end{strip}
    
\lipsum[2-15]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, it worked. And thanks for the advice. But did you know to move the image down a bit more?

Comment: I'm also having a little trouble with float \begin{figure*}[h/n/b]. It doesn't appear on the page it should be, but it does appear on the next page. Is it really like that? or is there a way to make it appear according to the page.

Comment: @Zarko: I think you mean the `stfloats` package.

Comment: @Ari, image is immediately after insertion in the text. If it is not on the right place, move point of strip insertion in text. BTW, `figure*` doesn't consider positioning options, it is always on the top of the next page from point of its insertion to text. Exception can be done by use of the `stfloats` package, which enable put image on the bottom of the same page (if there is enough space) at use spacing option [b].

Comment: @Bernard, you are right. I rewrite my comment again. Now hopeful correctly.

Comment: @Zarko, thanks. I'll try it

Comment: What do you mean by *"allow on other pages as enable figure\*"* (seems incomprehensible)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, a s I said in my previous comment. On the top of the next page.