# I would like to alter the Journal of American Chemical Society (JACS) template to two columns

Tags: overleaf

I am using a JACS template achemso-demo.tex from that I downloaded and imported into Overleaf.

I made my first draft with this template and that worked fine but I have been asked to change it to two columns, and I don't know how to do this.

There is an achemso.pdf file at [ctan.org](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/achemso) which if I search for 'two' has a section on setting up two columns.

I copied the following text into my .tex file near the top of the file.

```
\newcommand*\acs@layout@shared{%
\AtBeginDocument{\singlespacing}%
\twocolumn
\tolerance=2000\relax
\emergencystretch=10pt\relax
\geometry{
letterpaper,
top = 12.7mm,
bottom = 16.8mm,
left = 19.3mm,
right = 19.3mm
}%
\setlength{\columnsep}{8.1mm}%
\setlength{\parindent}{3.3mm}%
\renewenvironment{acknowledgement}{%
\def\@tempa{acknowledgement}%
\ifx\@currenvir\@tempa
\let\par\relax
\acksize
\vspace{6pt}%
\textbf{\acknowledgementname}%
\else
\acs@section*{\acknowledgementname}%
\fi
}{%
\acs@par
}%
}
```

And then I types the following lines at the location where I wanted the 2 columns to begin

```
\begingroup
\def\@tempa{twocolumn}
\ifx\acs@layout\@tempa
\aftergroup\acs@layout@shared
\fi
\def\@tempa{two-column}
\ifx\acs@layout\@tempa
\aftergroup\acs@layout@shared
\fi
\endgroup
⟨/class⟩
```

Would someone be able to tell me what I need to type into the .tex file and where in order for it to compile correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: Please add the code of your current attempt to the question, so we can start from there and hopefully fix the issue faster without the need to recreate the problem from scratch.

Comment: Please provide an MWE that we can compile that shows the problem and what you have done to try and fix it.

Comment: I added the code I added to the achemso-demo.tex file as an edit to my original comment .  Thanks.

Comment: To the original `achemso-demo.tex`   add  `\twocolumn`   after `\end{abstract}`

Comment: As easy as that.  I had tried that but I put it before the Abstract.  That was the problem.  I now have to figure out a way of making my figures cross both columns.  I will try the command \onecolumn immediately prior to the figure and see what effect that has.

Comment: Unfortunately if I place \onecolumn before \beginfigure and then \twocolumn after \endfigure I get unwanted space so now I need a way of using \twocolumn with a figure that straddles both columns.  I shall search online as the nature of my query has changed.  If I find a solution I shall comment.  Thanks

Comment: There is a simple solution to page wide figures in a twocolumn text:  use \beginfigure*
The solution is on tex.stackexchange:    https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/displaying-a-wide-figure-in-a-two-column-document

I have unwanted space between my abstract now and the two columns but I am getting there.  I shall resolve the query as the 2 columns and figure query are resolved. Thanks